# How to create unix alias with command substitution?

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to create an alias for the following.  Would you please let me know how to set this up?

```
mate  \`find . -name <filename>\`
```

Comment: (not clear whether you wanted the backslashes in there, please edit your post if that's not what you wanted)

Comment: Also unclear:  do you intend that `somealias foo` expands to that with `foo` in place of `<filename>`?  What about if multiple filenames are specified?  In any case, aliases are not generally the answer to this, except in `csh` derivatives; you want a shell function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a function instead: `mymate() { mate $(find . -name "$1"); }`

Comment: I believe you meant '$1' instead of '$!'

Answer (score 0):

This is an indirect solution. Put the command in a file (whithout .sh say cmdfile) under `~/bin` then give the alias as `alias myalias=cmdfile`